# secure upload/download file with carrierwave gem rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

Authenticate user can download and upload file , this is the main purpose of my project.I want to secure my file downloads, so that only authenticate user can download file. For this, I use `gem carrierwave`  and carrierwave/wiki ["How To: Secure Upload"](http://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-To%3A-Secure-Upload) . But when I click my download url , its says "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error"

Here is addfiles_controller.rb file:

```
class AddfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in

  def index
    @addfiles = Addfile.all
  end

  def new
    @addfile = Addfile.new
  end

  def create
    if admin_signed_in?
      @addfile = current_admin.addfiles.build(addfile_params)
    else
      @addfile = current_user.addfiles.build(addfile_params)
    end


    if @addfile.save
      redirect_to addfiles_path
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @addfile = Addfile.find(params[:id])
    @addfile.destroy
    redirect_to addfiles_path
  end


  def download
    path = "/#{addfile.addfile}"
    send_file path, :x_sendfile=>true
  end



  private
  def addfile_params
    params.require(:addfile).permit(:name, :attachment)
  end
end
```

config/initializers/carrierwave.rb file:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  # These permissions will make dir and files available only to the user running
  # the servers
  config.permissions = 0600
  config.directory_permissions = 0700
  config.storage = :file
  # This avoids uploaded files from saving to public/ and so
  # they will not be available for public (non-authenticated) downloading
  config.root = Rails.root
end
```

routes.rb file:

```
FileDownload::Application.routes.draw do

  match "/uploads/:id/:basename.:extension", :controller => "addfiles", :action => "download", via: :get

  resources :addfiles do
    collection  do
      get 'all_users'
    end
  end
  root "addfiles#index"
  devise_for :admins
  devise_for :users

end
```

in my views:

```
<%= link_to File.basename(file.attachment_url), "/uploads/#{file.id}/#{File.basename(file.attachment_url)}" %>
```

**attachment_uploader.rb file**

```
class AttachmentUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(pdf doc htm html docx)
  end

end
```

Error Trace::

```
Started GET "/uploads/13/ARTICLE_FINAL_.pdf" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-04 14:39:53 +0600
Processing by AddfilesController#download as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"13", "basename"=>"ARTICLE_FINAL_", "extension"=>"pdf"}
  ←[1m←[36mUser Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1←[0m
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms

NameError (undefined local variable or method `addfile' for #<AddfilesController:0x46baa10>):
  app/controllers/addfiles_controller.rb:37:in `download'


  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (47.0ms)
[2014-09-04 14:39:53] ERROR Errno::ECONNRESET: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:80:in `eof?'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:80:in `run'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

whats the problem here?? Please give me your suggestion.

Comment: Please paste your error trace here.

Comment: @anusha, i added error trace.

Comment: check your download method there you are specifying   `path = "/#{addfile.addfile}"` but you didn't have any field(attribute) like `addfile` for your model(I checked in permitted parameters).

Comment: yes, i know.  I just customize the download method  from this [link](http://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-To%3A-Secure-Upload). will you please tell me, how can i fixed this?

Comment: please paste your uploader file content here

Comment: Try to change this line `path = "/#{addfile.addfile}"` to `path = "/#{attachment.attachment}"`

Comment: its says.. NameError (undefined local variable or method `attachment'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60611/discussion-between-anusha-and-mezbah).

Comment: Did you solve the problem. If not, please try removing `path` variable in download method and change this `send_file` line as `    send_file '#{Rails.root}/uploads/addfile/#{file.id}', :type=>"application/image" `

Comment: Did it worked for you?

Comment: Works Only for image

Comment: Then remove that type option then you can get any file

Comment: Thanks you. That's works fine. Can i use array of options in types hash ? Because i have different type of files to download.

Comment: Yes, but if we are not mentioning also we can download any type of file i think

Comment: Hmmmm, you are great!!

Comment: You can write answer now..&  close the topic

Comment: I have posted answer for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change download method like this:

**addfiles_controller.rb:**

```
def download
      send_file '#{Rails.root}/uploads/addfile/#{file.id}'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work, similar to the same way you've setup and following the [Carrerwave Wiki](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/how-to:-secure-upload).

I am also using Pundit so have some authorisation in for context.

```
class RecordsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_record, only: :download

  def download
    authorize @record
    send_file @record.file.path 
    #where file is the name of the mount_uploader from the Record class
  end

  private

    def set_record 
      @record = Record.find(params[:id]) 
    end 
end
```